# Parsing multiple json like objects in a file

Tags: regex, nested, regex-group

I am trying to parse F5 object. It has below structure.

```
Some Garbage text
ltm virtual The_Name_51244_sdfasfdasd {
    address-status yes
    enabled
    fallback-persistence none
    profiles {
        /Common/GLOBAL_PROFILE {
            context all
        }
        /Common/http {
            context all
        }
    }
    rate-class none
    rules {
        /Common/X-F-F
    }
    log-profiles none
    source-address-translation {
        pool SOME-SNAT-POOL
        type snat
    }
    source-port preserve
    vlans {
        Vlan1111
    }
    service-down-immediate-action none
    service-policy none
    source 0.0.0.0/0
}
barbage text
ltm virtual The_Object_51244 {
    address-status yes
    enabled
    fallback-persistence none
    profiles {
        /Common/GLOBAL_PROFILE {
            context all
        }
        /Common/http {
            context all
        }
    }
    rate-class none
    rules {
        /Common/X-F-F
    }
    log-profiles none
    source-address-translation {
        pool SOME-SNAT-POOL
        type snat
    }
    source-port preserve
    vlans {
        Vlan2222
    }
    service-down-immediate-action none
    service-policy none
    source 0.0.0.0/0
}
Trailing garbage text
```

My regex is `((ltm virtual) ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*) {(.|\n)*?})`
https://regex101.com/r/ATJZys/1

What I am trying to capture is name after ltm virtual and everything between curly brackets. But, above regex seems to stop at first close curly bracket match.

How do I extent it to match until next parent group or match until curly brackets are balanced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
((ltm virtual) ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*) ({(?:[^{}]++|\g<4>)*}))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ATJZys/2).

*Details*:

- `(` - Group 1 start

  - `(ltm virtual)` - Group 2: `ltm virtual` string
  - - space
  - `([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)` - Group 3: zero or more letters, digits, underscores or hyphens (can be re-written as `[\w-]*`)
  - - space
  - `({(?:[^{}]++|\g<4>)*})` - Group 4: `{`, then zero or more repetitions of either one or more chars other than `{` and `}` or Group 4 recursed, and then a `}` char
- `)` - end of Group 1.

In Java, to match nested curly braces, or parentheses, or any other single char delimiters after a certain regex pattern (at the end of the pattern to be more precise) you can use

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Character markStart = '{';
        Character markEnd = '}';
        Boolean includeMarkers = true;
        int offset = (includeMarkers ? -1 : 0);
        String s = "Some Garbage text\r\nltm virtual The_Name_51244_sdfasfdasd {\r\n    address-status yes\r\n    enabled\r\n    fallback-persistence none\r\n    profiles {\r\n        /Common/GLOBAL_PROFILE {\r\n            context all\r\n        }\r\n        /Common/http {\r\n            context all\r\n        }\r\n    }\r\n    rate-class none\r\n    rules {\r\n        /Common/X-F-F\r\n    }\r\n    log-profiles none\r\n    source-address-translation {\r\n        pool SOME-SNAT-POOL\r\n        type snat\r\n    }\r\n    source-port preserve\r\n    vlans {\r\n        Vlan1111\r\n    }\r\n    service-down-immediate-action none\r\n    service-policy none\r\n    source 0.0.0.0/0\r\n}\r\nbarbage text\r\nltm virtual The_Object_51244 {\r\n    address-status yes\r\n    enabled\r\n    fallback-persistence none\r\n    profiles {\r\n        /Common/GLOBAL_PROFILE {\r\n            context all\r\n        }\r\n        /Common/http {\r\n            context all\r\n        }\r\n    }\r\n    rate-class none\r\n    rules {\r\n        /Common/X-F-F\r\n    }\r\n    log-profiles none\r\n    source-address-translation {\r\n        pool SOME-SNAT-POOL\r\n        type snat\r\n    }\r\n    source-port preserve\r\n    vlans {\r\n        Vlan2222\r\n    }\r\n    service-down-immediate-action none\r\n    service-policy none\r\n    source 0.0.0.0/0\r\n}\r\nTrailing garbage text";
        Pattern patternBefore = Pattern.compile("(ltm\\s+virtual)\\s+([\\w-]+)\\s+" + Pattern.quote(markStart.toString()));
        
        Matcher m = patternBefore.matcher(s);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Group 1: " + m.group(1));
            System.out.println("Group 2: " + m.group(2));
            String res = getBalancedSubstring(s.substring(m.end()), markStart, markEnd, includeMarkers);
            
            System.out.println("Found nested: " + res + "\n----");
            if (res == null) {
                System.out.println("No nested parens match found, this match must be failed.");
            }
            else {
                s = s.substring(m.end()+res.length() + offset);
                m.reset(s);
            }
        }
    }
    public static String getBalancedSubstring(String s, Character markStart, Character markEnd, Boolean includeMarkers) 
    {
        int level = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if (c == markStart) {
                level++;
            }
            else if (c == markEnd) {
                if (level == 1) {
                    return (includeMarkers ? markStart.toString() : "") + s.substring(0, (includeMarkers ? i + 1 : i));
                }
                if (level > 0) level--;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

See the [Java demo online](https://ideone.com/jwKxhq).

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly for PHP. But, seem to have problem using \g<4> in Java. Is there alternate solution to this ??

Comment: @randomkick Java regex does not support regex subroutines, you cannot use this pattern in Java.